# How to remove variable amount of consecutive NaN values from vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a vector of values such as the following:

```
1
2
3
NaN
4
7
NaN
NaN
54
5
2
7
2
NaN
NaN
NaN
5
54
3
2
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
4
NaN
```

How can I use

> interp1

in such way that only a variable amount of consecutive NaN-values would be interpolated? That is for example I would want to interpolate only those NaN-values where there are at most three consecutive NaN-values. So *NaN*, *NaN NaN* and *NaN NaN NaN* would be interpolated but not *NaN NaN NaN NaN*.

Thank you for any help =)

P.S. If I can't do this with interp1, any ideas how to do this in another way? =)

To give an example, the vector I gave would become:

```
1
2
3
interpolated
4
7
interpolated
interpolated
54
5
2
7
2
interpolated
interpolated
interpolated
5
54
3
2
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
4
interpolated
```

Comment: Are we assuming linear interpolation with each element of the vector being equally spaced from the next?

Comment: Yes =) That is correct

Comment: `interp1` would have a problem interpolating the last `NaN`. Just saying'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, find the positions and lengths of all sequences of `NaN` values:

```
nan_idx = isnan(x(:))';
nan_start = strfind([0, nan_idx], [0 1]);
nan_len = strfind([nan_idx, 0], [1 0]) - nan_start + 1;
```

Next, find the indices of the `NaN` elements not to interpolate:

```
thr = 3;
nan_start = nan_start(nan_len > thr);
nan_end = nan_start + nan_len(nan_len > thr) - 1;
idx = cell2mat(arrayfun(@colon, nan_start, nan_end, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Now, interpolate everything and replace the elements that shouldn't have been interpolated back with `NaN` values:

```
x_new = interp1(find(~nan_idx), x(~nan_idx), 1:numel(x));
x_new(idx) = NaN;
```

Comment: +1 excellent solution. I like the use of `@colon` in `arrayfun`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an bad habit in matlab, but I would think this particular case requires a loop:

```
function out = f(v)
  out = zeros(numel(v));
  k = 0;
  for i = 1:numel(v)
    if v(i) ~= NaN
      if k > 3
        out(i-k:i - 1) = ones(1, k) * NaN;             
      else
        out(i-k: i - 1) = interp1();%TODO: call interp1 with right params
      end
      out(i) = v(i)
      k = 0

    else
      k = k + 1 % number of consecutive NaN value encoutered so far
    end

 end
```

Comment: `k` is undefined in the first run through and what is `interpl()` ?